# Area of a region bounded by a circle and vertical line using integration

Tags: calculus, integration, analysis, circles, area

What is the area of the right region bounded by $x^2 + y^2 =25$ and $x = -3$?

My attempt solution: I solved first for the area of the left region and subtracted it from the area of the circle, which is

$$ 25 \pi - \int_{-4}^4 -3 + \sqrt {25-y^2} \,dy $$
$$ 78.5 - 11.18... = 67.36 $$
So, the area of the right region is 67.36.

My other solution is:
$$ \int_{0}^5 \sqrt {25-y^2} \,dy + \int_{0}^4 -(-3)\,dy + \int_{4}^5 -(-\sqrt {25-y^2})= 67.36$$

Are the area (67.36) and the integration process all correct? Is there more precise integration for the area of the right bounded region, without using double or triple integration?

Answer (score 1):

I think both of your approaches are correct.

I went about it the following way:

$25\pi - 2 \cdot \int_{-5}^{-3} \sqrt{(-5)^2 - x^2} = 67.36$. When integrating I got $arcsin(3/5)$, which is where I rounded my values. I do not think, there is a way to avoid this other than leaving arcsin(3/5) in your reslut, if you want it to be more precise.